# Predicting accuracy using two measure x1 and x2 and state which one is better

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, mathematical-statistics

I am interested in predicting Accuracy(Y) and am studying different two measure X1 and X2. It could be for instance that I want to predict the accuracy of a classifier , either by measure x1 or x2. I want to know which one of the measuring techniques is better.

I can create a linear model in R:
Accuracy equation  using measure 1  in regression is suppose = 87.321 - 0.1234* x1                                                                                                                                                  Accuracy equation  using measure 2  in regression is suppose = 90.321 - 0.434* x2
Now let's say X1 is a superior predictor of accuracy than X2. Because When calculating the R2( R squared ) of the two models, the R2 of model using X1 is clearly higher than R2 ( R squared) of model m2 using x2 .Is this right approach to compare two measure and state that this measure is more accuarte in predicting accuracy.

Is there any paper which are implemented this type of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

That would work, but if you are predicting a ratio or a percentage, that regression probably isn't the best choice. Instead, you could try transforming the dependent variable first, and modeling that. For example, predict Y' = log(y/(1 − y)). This makes interpreting the coefficients effect on the original variable difficult, but it doesn't sound like you need to. If you do, you'll want to do what's called beta regression.